# How do I install child-proof drawer latches on bottom drawers?

Tags: child-safety

Installing child safety latches for `cabinet doors` is relatively easy (here's a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4kaLkwmcmoI))

Similarly for the `top drawer` (pull-out) ([video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NMjlFDNjq4c))

But is it possible to do this for the bottom drawers?

The problem is that I have nothing to latch on to.

Comment: The second video shows the installation of something to latch onto. It may take some creativity, but there's usually a way to create something to latch onto. A photo of the removed drawer and the cabinet with the drawer removed would help illustrate your problem.

Comment: The top drawer latches on to the frame of the cabinet (as in video #2) however the next drawer has the top drawer immediately above it

Comment: Perhaps a metal angle bracket could be attached to the cabinet side, which projects over the drawer side such that a catch attached to one side of the rear of the drawer front would hook it. Hard to say what will work without seeing it.